# cefpython3 связь JS и Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Python 3.4. GUI - wxPython.

Необходимо вычислить размер текста в пикселях, объявленного в SVG документе.

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 {width} {height}" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="svg" height="100%" width="100%">
  <text font-family="{font}" font-size="{size}" id="user_text">{text}</text>
</svg>
```

Средствами Python и wxPython это сделать не получается. wxPython позволяет определить размеры, который будет занимать текст с определенным шрифтом, размером и т.д., но они не верны для SVG (из-за масштабирования svg-документа, как я понял).

Нашел способ вычисления размера текста через JS:

```
let text = document.getElementById("user_text");
let box = text.getBBox();
let w = box.width;
let h = box.height;
```

Это решение дает верный результат.

Мне необходимо использовать значения, вычисленные в JS, в моей GUI программе на Python.

Встроенные в wxPython web-движок такое не вытягивает (там какой-то старый IE).

Посоветовали библиотеку cefpython3 - Chromium Embedded Framework. Она позволяет подключить браузер к GUI. Это работает отлично.

Как я понял из туториала, из Python можно вызвать JS методы, предварительно их объявив. [GitHub/example](https://github.com/cztomczak/cefpython/blob/master/examples/tutorial.py)

Но мне никак не удается реализовать механизм, чтобы после выполнения функции JS вернуть результат обратно в Python и использовать его.

Возможно ли вообще такое? Если да, подскажите, пожалуйста, в какую сторону копать.

Comment: В общем случае это невозможно, хоть с cef, хоть без: размер текста сильно зависит от браузера, от ОС, от доступности шрифтов, от текущих настроек сглаживания и так далее (и я как верстальщик сильно страдаю от этого). Даже ваше решение на JS будет выдавать разные результаты в разных браузерах (попробуйте проверить в этом самом IE, например). Возможно, вас вполне устраивает *примерный* размер текста, но всё же счёл нужным написать это предупреждение на всякий случай

Comment: @andreymal, примерный размер текста вполне подойдет :) +- 1-2px особой роли не играют в моем случае. Мне нужно вычислить размер прямоугольника, который необходимо добавить перед текстом.

Comment: @andreymal, https://codepen.io/ioprst/pen/vbKEXJ?editors=1010, см. элемент с текстом "Test Text". Вполне приемлемый, на мой взгляд, результат.

Comment: Нет, у меня вылезло :) https://i.stack.imgur.com/dOzjD.png

Comment: @andreymal, жаль. Спасибо, что разбили всю мою веру в то, что я нашел решение проблемы :D (лучше сейчас, чем потом).

Comment: @andreymal, у вас IE выдал такой результат?

Comment: Firefox на Ubuntu Linux

Comment: Если вы весь svg генерируете сами, можно попробовать взять ширину с запасом (например, умножить на 1.1 или 1.2) и выровнять текст по центру (`text-anchor="middle"`) — тогда по краям слева и справа будет пустовато, но зато влезет и смотреться будет не слишком вырвиглазно (впрочем, к сути вопроса про вычисление ширины это уже слабо относится и такое обсуждение лучше вести в отдельном чате)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем, дали ссылку (разработчик) на пример попроще. Получилось следующее (неидеальное) решение:

```
import sys
import base64

from cefpython3 import cefpython as cef


def create_HTML(width, height, font, size, text):
    HTML_code = """
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <svg viewBox="0 0 {width} {height}" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="svg" height="100%" width="100%">
            <text font-family="{font}" font-size="{size}" id="user_text">{text}</text>
        </svg>
        <script type=text/javascript>
            function js_function() {{
                let text = document.getElementById("user_text");
                let box = text.getBBox();
                let w = box.width;
                let h = box.height;
                py_function(w, h, js_callback);
            }}
            function js_callback(py_callback) {{

            }}
        </script>
    </body>
    </html
    """.format(width=width, height=height, font=font, size=size, text=text)
    return HTML_code


def main():
    cef.Initialize()
    browser = cef.CreateBrowserSync(url=cef.GetDataUrl(create_HTML(256, 256, 'Courier New', 16, 'Test Text')))
    browser.SetClientHandler(LoadHandler())
    bindings = cef.JavascriptBindings()
    bindings.SetFunction("py_function", py_function)
    bindings.SetFunction("py_callback", py_callback)
    browser.SetJavascriptBindings(bindings)
    cef.MessageLoop()
    del browser
    cef.Shutdown()


def py_function(w, h, js_callback):
    print(w, h)
    # js_callback.Call("I am a Python string #2", py_callback)


def py_callback(w, h):
    pass


class LoadHandler(object):
    def OnLoadEnd(self, browser, **_):
        browser.ExecuteFunction("js_function")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

В py_function как раз те самые два float значения, которые необходимо было получить.